# 30018 warnings for messages sent via Conversations API

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-conversations

I am currently using the Conversations API to have two-way communication with customers.  Three phone numbers (Australian numbers) have been registered with `Twilio` for this purpose.
This feature is already live and users/customers are using it regularly.

However, recently `Twilio` has started logging `30018` warnings for all messages sent via the Conversation API. i.e. all outbound messages from my application to customers. As per Twilio documentation, the 30018 warning is when an Alphanumeric sender id, which is not pre-registered, is used to communicate with customers i.e. https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/errors/30018 .

Conversations API requires the use of phone numbers and not Alphanumeric Sender IDs.  As such, ideally, I should not be receiving this warning.  Yet, for every outbound message sent via the Conversations API, I am receiving this warning.  This is causing the error webhook to trigger every time an outbound message is sent.  This in turn is polluting my error inbox and the Twilio error listing.

Does anyone know why this warning is being triggered? How do I prevent it from triggering?

Answer (score 0):

Technically, a phone number is an alphanumeric number. The [page](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/errors/30018#possible-solutions) you referenced gives a few options to resolve. It appears that Australia requires registering for [Sender Id](https://twlo.my.salesforce-sites.com/SenderId) and this page has info [Interational Support for Alphanumeric Sender Id](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223133767-International-support-for-Alphanumeric-Sender-ID).

Here is this [page](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/13111723633691-Documents-Required-and-Instructions-to-Register-Your-Alphanumeric-Sender-ID-in-Australia) specifically for Australia, which seems to have changed requirements on April 23, 2023:

> Documents Required and Instructions to Register Your Alphanumeric
> Sender ID in Australia
>
> Before we begin Effective April 25, 2023,
> dynamic Alphanumeric Sender IDs won’t be allowed in Australia. All
> Alphanumeric Sender IDs must be pre-registered to send messages in
> Australia. Messages sent using Alphanumeric Sender IDs that aren’t
> pre-registered by April 25, 2023 may be blocked at this time. Twilio
> reserves the right to block customers who have not registered by the
> specified date; we may block customer traffic sooner if we receive
> notice from ACMA to do so.

Comment: Phone number registration is already done though.  I am aware that there are changes for Australia.  However, all of them are related to AlphaNumberic Sender IDs which are handled very differently compared to phone numbers.

Since the phone number registration is already done, ideally I should not be receiving the warnings.

Comment: Your next option seem to be to open a ticket with Twilio. They are usually very responsive.

Comment: Yes.  Did that a couple of days back.  Got a response to manually turn off the warnings.  However, did not get a response as to why the warnings were generated for a phone number.

In either case, I am not getting the warnings anymore and my error callback is not being triggered unnecessarily which is good.

This should not be an issue for any Alpha Numeric Sender IDs that I may register later as I will be doing the due process and making sure all documentation is being sent across for registration.  Cheers.